# Loop and List - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function

The code -

```
def f(i=[]):
  i.append(1)
  return i
print(f())
print(f())
```

The Output -

```
[1]
[1, 1]
```

Why the function f() returns [1,1] as 2nd output instead of [1], because it assigns a new list every time when calling, but the list keeps appending the number...
Is there any reason

Thank you